# Need to calculate the size of image in bytes - for images from phonegap camera

Tags: image, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on a functionality, where I am uplaoding an image after capturing it from native camera. Here,  have a limitation regarding size of the image. So, I need to calculate the image Size in MB.

```
Camera.getPicture(gotPicture, cameraError, {
                                quality: 50,
                                allowEdit: true,
                                targetWidth: 200,
                                targetHeight: 200,
                                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                            });
camera
                        .getPicture(
                            gotPicture,
                            cameraError, {
                                quality: 100,
                                allowEdit: true,
                                targetWidth: 200,
                                targetHeight: 200,
                                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                            });
```

I found lot of suggestions where it is being save as a file, but here I am receiving it as DATA URI(As I need to pass Base64 Image for processing).

Can someone help in calculating the actual size of the image clicked/referenced from PHOTO_GALLERY.

I have one more query as when I am calling the Phonegap API, Is there any compression of size is being done at the API level,

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I don't think there's an overall answer to this. The size will be depending on the device camera. So I'd rather try to figure out how to compress a given picture to the needed size, than trying to get the quality right for every device out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get both size and Base64 data of the image like following:

```js
function capturePhoto() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: true});
}
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
 getSize(imageURI);
}
function onFail(message) {
   alert('Failed');
}
function getSize(fileUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
          fileUri,
          function(fileEntry){
           fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata){
            alert("size is"+metadata.size);
           }, resOnError);
           fileEntry.file( function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                alert(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }, resOnError);
          },
          resOnError);
}
function resOnError(error) {
 alert("error");
   }
```

You can do this for Photo gallery by setting `sourceType :Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`.And for compression of size I recommend you to set lower quality in `getPicture`.

Comment: Here, when I'm choosing image of 2.5MB, it is showing size : 178908 & when I'm choosing image of size 8.9MB, it is showing size : 88412, which is not correct. I have used the code given above. Please help.