# Convert URI to FIle Object JS

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app , Using cordova-fileChooser plugin i am able to get the Uri of the selected File .

[image]

Then Using cordova-plugin-filepath  i got the absolute path of the file  from the nativeURL on the phone

[image]

How do i get the file object from this path or Uri ? 
I want to append it to a formData and post it .

Comment: Are you want to upload the file?

Comment: Yes I wanna upload the file

Comment: Then you can use cordova file transfer plugin.There you need to give the file url

Comment: Oh ok that worked ... you can answer it so that I can select it and up vote

Comment: Ok @Jeson I added the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cordova file transfer plugin.In this plugin you need to give the file url to `upload`.Reference is here [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

Comment: i wanted the object because i wanted file size and mime-type ,so that i could perform some file validations . Any idea how that could be done from the Uri ?

Comment: you can check my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38454556/5887638    . Pass the FileURL to getSize() function . As you don't require base64 image, so comment lower part after the size is alert.

Comment: i managed to find this : = `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURL, function (fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(
                            function (file) {
                                console.log("File__++ ", file);}'
                                options.fileName = file.name;
                                fileSize = file.size;
                                $scope.filename = options.fileName;`

Comment: I can access all of the file's metadata and managed to validate :)